# How can i change my image when connection to internet is fired offline or online,

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

```
        <script>


            function myFunction() {

                if (navigator.onLine) {
                    swal("Great News" , 'Congratulation your connection is online', "success");
                } else {
                    swal("Sad News" , 'Can you please connect to the internet to login', "error");
                }

            }

            </script>
```

I would like to add a function whereby the image is changed depending whether the users connection to the internet is offline or online

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events#Example

Comment: Can you please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Your current code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set a custom function like

```
 window.addEventListener("online" , _=>{
            //set image online
        })
        window.addEventListener("offline" , _=>{
            //set image offline
        })
```

like

```js
        
 

            
 var img1 = document.getElementById("wifi-image")       
 function changeimage(online){
 
 if(online) {
 img1.src ="online-wifi.png"
 img1.alt ="online-wifi.png"
 }
 else{
 img1.src ="offline-wifi.png"
  img1.alt ="offline-wifi.png"
 }
}

 window.addEventListener("online" , _=>{
                //set image online
 changeimage(true)
            })
            window.addEventListener("offline" , _=>{
                //set image offline
 changeimage(false)
            })
            
            // at start
             changeimage(navigator.onLine)
```

```html
<img id="wifi-image" src="" alt="online-mode">
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, could you please show an example of how to add the images so say the image is wifi.png

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that you have mentioned Cordova tag, So I'm assuming that it is for a mobile app.

You can store the image in the cache by using imgcache

https://github.com/chrisben/imgcache.js/

but this will not work if your app has not connected to the internet even once because then it'll not have a file for reference.

Let me know if you find any difficulties.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

**in HTML :**

```
<img id="imgID" src="img.png"/>
```

**in JavaScript :**

```
if(navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE){
   console.log("device is offline");
    //you can now call picture from your folder
    $("#imgID").attr("src","img.png");

}else{
   console.log("device is online");
   //you can now call picture from internet like this
   $("#imgID").attr("src","https://website.com/img.png");
}
```